# Using a Raspberry Pi as a Remote Screen for Windows

Tags: pi-2

My current screen setup in windows consists of my Laptop screen and a HDMI screen.

Since I have extra screens laying around, I wanted to know if I can use my PI to connect to a monitor remotely (hdmi or vga with an adapter whatever) instead of buying an expensive dongle for my pc.
I have a Raspberry Pi 2 model B (old I know).

Basically 'smartifying a screen for "Extended Screen" setup in windows using a pi'

Comment: See [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) to see how this site works
and [How do I ask a good question?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)